# elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(N/A, 'Unable to sniff hosts.')

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have installed Elasticsearch on ubuntu VM, just one node. When I index data, the error as below:

```html
  File "/data/apps/ecoboost/eggs/elasticsearch-2.4.0-py2.7.egg/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/data/apps/ecoboost/eggs/elasticsearch-2.4.0-py2.7.egg/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 452, in update
    doc_type, id, '_update'), params=params, body=body)
  File "/data/apps/ecoboost/eggs/elasticsearch-2.4.0-py2.7.egg/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 324, in perform_request
    connection = self.get_connection()
  File "/data/apps/ecoboost/eggs/elasticsearch-2.4.0-py2.7.egg/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 181, in get_connection
    self.sniff_hosts()
  File "/data/apps/ecoboost/eggs/elasticsearch-2.4.0-py2.7.egg/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 250, in sniff_hosts
    node_info = self._get_sniff_data(initial)
  File "/data/apps/ecoboost/eggs/elasticsearch-2.4.0-py2.7.egg/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 213, in _get_sniff_data
    raise TransportError("N/A", "Unable to sniff hosts.")
elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(N/A, 'Unable to sniff hosts.')
```

ES client config:

```html
es_client = Elasticsearch(settings.ELASTICSEARCH_DATA_NODES,
                                 sniff_on_start=False,
                                 sniff_on_connection_fail=True,
                                 sniffer_timeout=60)
```

How to understand the sniff host? How to solve this problem? Hope anyone can help me, thanks in advance!